# Como ler números do teclado em C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Eu sei que `getchar()` obtém caracteres do teclado por `stdin`, porém quero saber como introduzir números em uma variável.

Pois se uso `getchar()` e digito um `2`, por exemplo, a variável torna-se `50`, e obviamente não é o que eu quero.

Comment: C, C# ou C++? Tô confuso.

Comment: As respostas aqui, até agora, funcionam, para um exercício rápido, mas para uso geral é preciso um pouco mais para garantir que a entrada está correta.

Comment: Tem `stdin` em C#? Espera, tem a tag C, mas o título da pergunta é C#, espera, ali tem C++ também, mas que confusão!

Comment: Por favor quando for postar sua pergunta coloque de forma clara e objetiva com informações detalhadas sobre o que você necessita e qual ou quais linguagens você estará utilizando.Sua pergunta ficou muito complicada de se entender,e usou as tags ainda somente para complicar mais. Por isto vou dar -1 para sua pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

Bem, você não especificou a linguagem, então vamos lá:

## C

Para ler um número, vou supor que seja uma int, em C o seguinte código é usado:

```
int meuNumero; scanf("%d", &meuNumero);
```

## C++

Para ler um número em C++ usamos a stream `cin` com o operador `>>`:

```
int meuNumero; cin >> meuNumero;
```

## C#

Em C# temos que chamar o método `Console.ReadLine` para lermos a entrada e `Convert.ToInt32` ou `Int32.Parse` para transformarmos para um número:

```
int meuNumero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

Answer (score 3):

Se for C# você pode usar o `Console.ReadLine()` mas não se esqueça que o `ReadLine()` retorna uma String, por isso, é preciso converter. Você pode usar o `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`.

Então fica: 
`int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`.

Se você digitar uma String que não seja int, provavelmente você receberá uma exceção.

Se você estiver usando C, com a biblioteca stdio.h, você conseguirá pegar um int usando o famoso `scanf()`.

Então fica:

```
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);
```

Por fim, se tiver usando C++, você pode sempre usar o namespace sdt.

Então fica:

```
int input;
std::cin >> input;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Na linguagem C, use `getch()` para capturar o primeiro caractere digitado, exemplo:

```
char op;
op=getch(); //Lê a primeira tecla que for digitado no teclado, e grava na variável
printf("Caractere digitado: %c", op); //Printa na tela o caractere digitado
```

Se quiser gravar mais de um caractere em uma variável usa o `scanf()` como já exemplificado nas outras respostas.

Se você quiser receber apenas números e fazer cálculos com eles use o `scanf()` utilizando variáveis do tipo int para numeros inteiros e float para não inteiros, por exemplo:

```
//Fazendo cálculos com números inteiros
int a, b, result_int;
printf("Digite o primeiro valor: \n");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Digite o segundo valor: \n");
scanf("%d", &b);

result_int = a + b;
printf("a + b = %d\n", result_int); //Printa na tela o resultado da soma

//Fazendo cálculos com números não inteiros
float c, d, result_float;
printf("Digite o primeiro valor: \n");
scanf("%f", &c);
printf("Digite o segundo valor: \n");
scanf("%f", &d);

result_float = c + d;
printf("c + d = %f\n", result_float); //Printa na tela o resultado da soma
printf("c + d = %.2f\n", result_float); //Printa na tela o resultado da soma, limitando as casas depois da virgula para melhor visual
```

Compila o código para você entender melhor rsrs.